# Automate a running counter through a document

Tags: counters, calculations

The following minimal example demonstrates my situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\newcommand{\pts}{0}

\begin{document}

\ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts

\ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts

\ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts
    \item \ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts
\end{enumerate}

\pts

\end{document}
```

Ideally I would like to have the counter `\pts` to increase through and after the application of the enumeration environment (or any environment in fact). The package document does state:

> But these commands act
>   as declarations, so that its scope is local in environments and groups.

Is there a way around this? Is there a way to keep a counter running through a document, that one can add (or other arithmetic operations as needs be, which the calculator package does do wonderfully).

Comment: Well, you basically ask for a `total` sum counter?

Comment: Yes. I thought that this was a way, but it doesn't work within environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `\pts` global before leave the `enumerate` environment.
To do this, use the `\GLOBALCOPY` command: `\GLOBALCOPY{\pts}{\pts}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\newcommand{\pts}{0}

\begin{document}

\ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts

\ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts

\ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts

\begin{enumerate}
   \item \ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts
   \item \ADD{\pts}{3}{\pts}\pts
   \GLOBALCOPY{\pts}{\pts}             %%%% Globalize \pts !!!
\end{enumerate}

\pts

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer; and for the package!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a counter rather than a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{pts}

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{pts}{3}\thepts

\addtocounter{pts}{3}\thepts

\addtocounter{pts}{3}\thepts

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \addtocounter{pts}{3}\thepts
    \item \addtocounter{pts}{3}\thepts
\end{enumerate}

\thepts

\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't work with floating point values, if that should be intented

Comment: @Christian: Well, that wasn't in the question...!

Comment: No, it wasn't, just as tiny remark by me

Comment: @Christian: The word "counter", in my mind, implies an integer.

Comment: @Joce Many thanks. Christian was correct, I didn't mention since I didn't think about that. I suppose my MWE was too minimal!